# Solutions to a system of linear equations

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

earlier in the question I was required to convert an augmented matrix to its row-reduced echelon form. I ended up with this:

**$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 2 & -1 & -3 \\
    0 & 1 & -k-3 & -5 \\
    0 & 0 & k^2-2k & 5k+11 
  \end{array}\right]
$$**

the question I'm stuck on asks:
For what value(s) of k does the system have

**.** no solutions

**.** a unique solution

**.** infinitely many solutions

Comment: Suppose that you just had numbers there instead of expressions involving $k$. What patterns would you look for in the reduced matrix for each of the three possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

The system has no solution if :
k =2 or k =0 ,and k not= -11/5
the system has unique solution if :
K  does not have any of these values 2 or 0 and  -11/5 . that's for all value except 2,0,-11/5
and the system i think does not have infinitely many solutions because then k should have two different values simultanously and i have some doubt about the unique solution also .

Comment: i mean k should not be equal to -11/5

Comment: and what i find is that the only possibility for the system is inconsistency (no solution)